# Set 'end of document' signal within PDF from LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf

So I am developing a LaTeX document that will have several copies of the same or similar 'document' within it. Eg pages 1-10 might be a proforma pre-populated with someone's name and details, and then pages 11-15 might be a different proforma with different name and details, no. of pages etc. Sure, I could output one proforma to one PDF file, but I was hoping to output one PDF with all of the proformas in it.

Problem is, need them to print double sided, stapled - one stapled 'pack' for each of the constituent documents within a single PDF file. Is it even possible to do this, and if so, can LaTeX do it? Some sort of 'end of this document, staple' signal to send to printer/photocopier etc. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Load the class with the `twoside` option and use `\cleardoublepage` before to start the new data.

Comment: @Sigur this will not do the stapling... I don't think that part of the question is possible.

Comment: @PaulGessler, it sounds like a chapter for a book. Different margins and new chapter to split the document. I'm confused, sorry.

Comment: It's not a book, it's data collection forms for people to fill in once they're printed out. I know I can't set it to 'staple' from within LaTeX, but I can set stapling and double sided in the 'file->print' dialog box, I'm just wondering if there's a way to fool a printer in to thinking that different points in the PDF file represent the end of a document (so staple) etc

Comment: Can a printer even do that?

Comment: Well we use big photocopiers that are also printers. In their settings dialogs you can set stapling and double sided options etc no problem. The issue is whether we can programatically control docunent separation from within a PDF... I am guessing the consensus is not...

Answer (score 1):

**Not really**

What you want is only doable with [Portable Job Tickets](http://www.prepressure.com/library/technology/pjtf). There is currently no software support for creating them (although that may be possible with LuaTeX) and only high-end printers (or print shops) will handle them.